# How can I convert one letter to upper case in a word. Like wiki to wIkI

Tags: python

How can I convert one letter to upper case in a word. For example wiki to wIkI, I know how to capitalize it I can only get the whole word capitalized or I can only get the one letter capitalized.

Comment: if it's the same letter you can just use the_word.replace( lowercase, uppercase )

Comment: This is a very basic question which is readily answered by the documentation. Please refer to the official docs before posting next time. http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace

Answer (score 1):

why not just use `str.replace`?

```
word = 'wiki'
letter = 'i'
print word.replace(letter,letter.upper())
```

You could do the same thing with slightly more effort using `string.maketrans` and `str.translate`

```
import string
trans = string.maketrans(letter,letter.upper())
print word.translate(trans)
```

This latter form *may* be more efficient if you're using the same translation table repeatedly, but it's unlikely you'll notice a difference in runtime unless this is in a really tight loop.  The latter form is also very nice for making a few substitutions.  For example, to make all vowels uppercase, you would use:

```
trans = string.maketrans('aeiou','AEIOU')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
a = 'text'
b = ('t', 'x')
print ''.join(x.upper() if x in b else x for x in a)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just "i", You can do

```
string = string.replace('i','I')
```

Or, if there are more letters, try something like this:

```
letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
string = 'acgfdb'
for l in letters:
    string = string.replace(l.lower(),l.upper())
```

OK, according to your comment you also want to get input from user, try this then...

```
string = raw_input('Enter a word: ')
letter = raw_input('Enter the letter to change to capital: ')
while len(letter) != 1:
    print 'enter a single letter'
    letter = raw_input('Enter the letter to change: ')
string = string.replace(l.lower(),l.upper())
print string
```

Comment: I have to ask the user for a word, then the letter they want to change, that is the hard part